# Reading/writing binary file returns 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a script that dumps class info into a binary file, then another script that retrieves it.

Since binary files only accept chars, I wrote three functions for reading and writing Short Ints, Ints, and Floats. I've been experimenting with them so they're not overloaded properly, but they all look like this:

```
void writeInt(ofstream& file, int val) {
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&val), sizeof(val));
}
int readInt(ifstream& file) {
    int val;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&val), sizeof(val));
    return val;
}
```

I'll put the class load/save script at the end of the post, but I don't think it'll make too much sense without the rest of the class info.

Anyway, it seems that the file gets saved properly. It has the correct size, and all of the data matches when I load it. However, at some point in the load process, the file.read() function starts returning 0xCCCCCCCC every time. This looks to me like a read error, but I'm not sure why, or how to correct it. Since the file is the correct size, and I don't touch the seekg() function, it doesn't seem likely that it's reaching the end of file prematurely. I can only assume it's an issue with my read/write method, since I did kind of hack it together with limited knowledge. However, if this is the case, why does it read all the data up to a certain point without issue?

The error starts occurring at a random point each run. This may or may not be related to the fact that all the class data is randomly generated.

Does anyone have experience with this? I'm not even sure how to continue debugging it at this point.

Anyway, here are the load/save functions:

```
void saveToFile(string fileName) {
    ofstream dataFile(fileName.c_str());
    writeInt(dataFile, inputSize);
    writeInt(dataFile, fullSize);
    writeInt(dataFile, outputSize);
    // Skips input nodes - no data needs to be saved for them.
    for (int i = inputSize; i < fullSize; i++) {    // Saves each node after inputSize
        writeShortInt(dataFile, nodes[i].size);
        writeShortInt(dataFile, nodes[i].skip);
        writeFloat(dataFile, nodes[i].value);
        //vector<int> connects;
        //vector<float> weights;
        for (int j = 0; j < nodes[i].size; j++) {
            writeInt(dataFile, nodes[i].connects[j]);
            writeFloat(dataFile, nodes[i].weights[j]);
        }
    }
    read(500);
}
void loadFromFile(string fileName) {
    ifstream dataFile(fileName.c_str());
    inputSize = readInt(dataFile);
    fullSize = readInt(dataFile);
    outputSize = readInt(dataFile);
    nodes.resize(fullSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
        nodes[i].setSize(0);    // Sets input nodes
    }

    for (int i = inputSize; i < fullSize; i++) {    // Loads each node after inputSize
        int s = readShortInt(dataFile);
        nodes[i].setSize(s);
        nodes[i].skip = readShortInt(dataFile);
        nodes[i].value = readFloat(dataFile);
        //vector<int> connects;
        //vector<float> weights;
        for (int j = 0; j < nodes[i].size; j++) {
            nodes[i].connects[j] = readInt(dataFile); //Error occurs in a random instance of this call of readInt().
            nodes[i].weights[j] = readFloat(dataFile);
        }
        read(i); //Outputs class data to console
    }
    read(500);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never check the stream state when reading.  That's bad.

Comment: ... or writing. or that file was opened... You also want to open them (for reading and writing) as binary

Comment: What's a `node`? And what does `read` do? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You should take advantage of *function overloading* and use one function name for writing int, short, etc.  You could use a template too.  IMHO, all this extra work for a single statement?

Comment: Try writing and reading an `int`, before you attempt a complex class. Small steps.

Comment: I don't think `node` is relevant - the issue is within the read and write functions.

Comment: Thomas, I already spoke on overloading and templates. I'm still experimenting with the functions.

Comment: Passer, there's a comment in the code that explains what `read` does. Seriously, does nobody read before commenting?

Comment: BTW, there is an overhead for executing a function (which consumes processing time), such as pushing variables onto a stack or making copies of registers.  A branch or call instruction may cause the processor's instruction pipeline to be reloaded (again a waste of time).  Then there is the set up for returning a value.  All this overhead can be removed by not using functions for single line statements.  (Some compilers *may* optimize away the overhead, depending on the optimization settings).

Comment: Artemy thank you, I had that in there before, but took it out when playing with it. It looks like that was my error!

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but I'd rather correct critical bugs before working on optimizing my program, especially when I'm experimenting with methods.

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging this?  I'd expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB.  Please [edit] your question to summarize what the debugging tools told you and why they didn't solve your problem.  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @TobySpeight, I knew the source of the issue via debugging. This was mentioned in the original post. This question was solved by Artemy Vysotsky, but was not posted as an answer.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, if you post your response as an answer, I will mark the question as solved.

Comment: It's helpful for readers to know *what kind of debugging* you've done, as waiting for a crash with GDB is very different from finding uses of uninitialised variables or wild pointers with Valgrind.  And it turns out that the error seems to be in code you didn't even show us; that's why we ask for a [mcve].

Comment: @TobySpeight, not sure what you're talking about. `ofstream dataFile(fileName.c_str());` is the second line of code in my second posted chunk, and Artemy noticed that it wasn't declared properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the result of open, read, write operations.

And you need to open files (for reading and writing) as binary.